# Displaying an Image from a DB in an Image Control

Tags: wpf, image

I've saved an image in my DataBase in a parameter type image and I've done this with:

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UsuariosBLL bll = new UsuariosBLL();
        UsuariosBO user = new UsuariosBO();
        PerfilBO perfil = cmbperf.SelectedItem as PerfilBO;

        //........            
        user.Imagen = ConvertImageToByteArray(ruta);
        bll.InsertarFilaUsuarios(user);
        MessageBox.Show("Se insertó");
        //.......
    }
```

where the method ConvertToByteArray convert the image selected in a Byte Array

```
public byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(string path)
    {
        byte[] ImageByte=null;

        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            ImageByte = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
        return ImageByte;
    }
```

and now I just wanna retrieve the image selecting a different user in my combobox. 
I've tried like this:

```
private void cmbUsuarios_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UsuariosBO user = e.AddedItems[0] as UsuariosBO;
       //.....
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(user.Imagen);
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        imgFoto = img;
        usuario = user;
    }
```

But a error born:

Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Controls.Image'

I understand what it means but I don't know how to fix it...

thanks !!

Comment: if this is WPF, please delete all your code and use proper DataBinding. also, remove `System.Drawing` stuff, WPF does not care about that.

Comment: As a side comment, please code strictly in English. I'm a Spanish speaker just like you, though 100% of my code is strictly in English. People have no idea what `btnAceptar` means, nor should they.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a `System.Drawing.Image` from the byte stream, you should create a WPF `ImageSource` and assign that to the `Source` property of your ImageControl.

One way to do this is by creating a `BitmapImage`:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(user.Imagen))
{
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();
    img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    img.StreamSource = ms;
    img.EndInit();
    imgFoto.Source = img;
}
```

Or alternatively a `BitmapFrame`:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(user.Imagen))
{
    imgFoto.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(ms,
        BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```